# After locking computer both monitors show secondary screen

Tags: windows-8

I have noticed a problem that happens once in a while on my machine since I have installed Windows 8. When I lock my computer it will *sometimes* when I wake it have both monitors black with the mouse moving on both of them. I am able to go off the left side of the screen (where the main monitor should be) as well as push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and type in my password. Once the desktop loads both monitors are simply showing my secondary monitor.

The only fix that I have found for this is to reset the machine. Has anyone else seen this behavior, and does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Just an usual dual-monitor setup with graphics card? Or laptop + external? Have you looked into updated drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: I'd try what Jeff said, and if that doesn't help maybe go in and tell Windows to never turn the monitors off for power saving.

Comment: It is a desktop system with dual monitors. All drivers are up to date as well.

Comment: @MarkAllen Thanks for the tip about power saving. I have done that. This is still a very strange behavior, but at least there is a way to get around it. If you put that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @Adkins done. Power saving has always been tricky because it requires really specific cooperation between the hardware and the driver and the OS and for whatever reason it doesn't always work as desired. I don't know if it's small differences in the implementation of standards or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem with power saving modes - try setting Windows to *never* power your monitors off.